# 403 error for subdirectory application in IIS

Tags: angular, url-rewriting, iis-8

I have hosted a angular application in IIS in subdirectoy which is application. It works fine when user browse to http://host-url/beta/.

It does not work if user types in http://host-url/beta and shows 403 Forbidden error.

Whenever user types in wrong url I want to redirect user to http://host-url/beta/.

Let me know how can I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be really helpful if someone can guide me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was having different application pool for parent and subsite.